# Vue Removing Item From Array on Click Without Knowing Arrays Name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, vue.js

I am trying to add functionality of removing an item from an array when something is clicked. I currently have:

```
<span @click="deleteItem(index)" v-for="(item, index) in customTaxonomies.featured" v-html="item"></span>
```

And then in my methods I have:

```
deleteItem: function(index) {
   this.customTaxonomies.featured.splice(index, 1);
}
```

So this works, but the array I want to effect needs to be known in my method to do this (customTaxonomies.featured). Is there a way to pass the name of the array I want to target through the v-for loop like I am doing with index?

So possibly something like this:

```
<span @click="deleteItem(index, arrayName)" v-for="(item, index, arrayName) in customTaxonomies.featured" v-html="item"></span>
```

```
deleteItem: function(index, arrayName) {
   this.arrayName.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Or pass the name of the array through a prop or something from the frontend? My main goal is passing the name of the array I want to delete the item from, using the frontend of my application.

Comment: You are passing `array` itself instead of arrayname, which is not a good idea though

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing the name of the array, you would use

```
this[arrayName].splice(index, i)
```

If you pass the array itself, it would just be

```
arrayName.splice(index, i)
```